# Docker: Logging From Both App and Server In One Container

Tags: php, logging, nginx, docker, logentries

I want to use a centralized log catcher like Logentries, but I don't want its agent running inside all of my containers. Thus I plan for each service to log to its container's stdout, which is then passed to Logentries via the Docker API or a logging container.

**The question:** How do I handle a container that needs to output two logs? How do I keep them clean and separate without introducing another logging mechanism?

**The scenario:** I have a PHP app, which necessitates three components: Nginx, PHP-FPM, and my code. I can put Nginx and PHP-FPM in separate Docker containers, so they'll have separate logs, so we're good there. But my PHP has to be in the same container as Nginx so that it can be served, right?
When my app needs to log something (using [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog)), I can send it to the stdout of the container (e.g., make the log file a link to /dev/stdout), but then I can't keep the logs for Nginx and my app separate.

Is there a way to do that? Or am I looking at this all wrong? Is there a better way to run Nginx + PHP in Docker?

Comment: I don't know too much about the logging aspect, but "But my PHP has to be in the same container as Nginx so that it can be served, right?" is definitely a wrong assumption. I'm running them in separate containers, they cooperate via TCP/IP.

Comment: You're right. That is a wrong assumption, but my PHP does have to be in the same container as PHP-FPM, which presents the same type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having not found a better solution, I ended up having Laravel/Monolog log to a file in a mounted volume. The Logentries agent then collects the log from the container's host. This allows my container to remain as clean as possible in that I'm not installing Supervisor or a logging agent, and it allows whatever is running the container to access the log with minimal effort.

Logging to stdout turned out not to be an option because PHP-FPM wraps each line of output from the child process so as to make it difficult to parse, and in the case of JSON logs, entirely useless. (See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/highload-php-en/VXDN8-Ox9-M)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the Logentries [Docker logging integration](https://github.com/nearform/docker-logentries)?

Comment: Yes, but that just wraps the Docker logging APIs, which only support one log per container.

Comment: @jchamberlain unless I'm misunderstanding, without using the Docker logging APIs, your options are either: 1) use something like the phusion [base image](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) which lets you run multiple processes, then set up either the Logentries agent or install & configure syslog/rsyslog/... or 2) integrate one of our client libraries with your respective projects. HTH

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to separate your application into two containers, it's actually the recommended way to do it (Remember: one process per container).

Simply use a docker-compose.yml file like this(or manually launch them):

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 9000

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And a nginx.conf file like this:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Using this kind of configuration, you will now have 2 containers from which you can manage logs separatly using the docker logging facilities.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but you misunderstand the original question. Having put PHP-FPM and Nginx into separate containers, one still needs to output two logs from the PHP container: one for FPM and one for the app itself.

Comment: Ok, maybe simply use a filter in something like logstash to separate the fpm logs from the app log.